# TestAccuracy above 1 in Caffe training

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I was training an bvlc_googlenet using Caffe on a set of images with 5 output values. The results of testing I received is very unclear for me as test accuracy in many cases was above 1. How should I interpret those results? Is it an error?

Here are test logs of the trainning obtained using command
`/home/ubuntu/caffe/tools/extra/parse_log.sh train.log`

https://pastebin.com/8KN6g7Rx

Comment: yes, this is an error. There is no such thing as accuracy>1.

Comment: there is an open PR fixing this issue. do not use accuracy during training, only for test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this caffe Pull Request](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/5987) fixing this bug.

As a workaround (if you do not want to merge this PR) you can use Accuracy only during testing and disable it for training.